# RabbitMQ RPC How to automatically delete the callback queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I would like to know how to delete the *callback queue* after the client receive the callback message. After multiples RPC calls I have a lot of *callback* queues I'm  not using any more.

I declare the *callback queue* as following:

```
replyToQueueName = _channelListener.QueueDeclare(durable: false,
exclusive: false, autoDelete: true, arguments: null).QueueName;
```

I thought they were going to be deleted after use but this is not the case. I can see with the management plugin the queues still have a consumer.

Maybe I just must delete the queue after receive the callback message, but I'm not sure is the best approach: `channel.QueueDelete("queue-name", false, false);`

I've been using this [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution (not sure if is the best solution).
After receive the callback message, I unsubscribe the consumer:

`channel.BasicCancel(consumer.ConsumerTags[0]);`

This way the callback queue has no consumer, and it's deleted immediately.

[Cancelling a Consumer (Unsubscribing)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#unsubscribing)